# Benefits of actor pattern in HTTP handler

Tags: go, concurrency

I've been reading a few go blogs and and more recently I stubbled upon Peter Bourgon's talk titled "Ways to do things". He shows a few examples of the actor pattern for concurrency in GO. Here is a handler example using such pattern:

```
func (a *API) handleNext(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var (
        notFound   = make(chan struct{})
        otherError = make(chan error)
        nextID     = make(chan string)
    )
    a.action <- func() {
        s, err := a.log.Oldest()
        if err == ErrNoSegmentsAvailable {
            close(notFound)
            return
        }
        if err != nil {
            otherError <- err
            return
        }
        id := uuid.New()
        a.pending[id] = pendingSegment{s, time.Now().Add(a.timeout), false}
        nextID <- id
    }
    select {
    case <-notFound:
        http.NotFound(w, r)
    case err := <-otherError:
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    case id := <-nextID:
        fmt.Fprint(w, id)
    }
}
```

And there's a loop behind the scenes listening for the `action` channel:

```
func (a *API) loop() {
    for {
        select {
        case f := <-a.action:
            f()
        }
    }
}
```

My question is what is the benefit to all of this? The handler isn't any faster because it is still blocking until some action in the action func returns something to it. Which is essentially the same thing as just returning the function from outside the go routine. What am I missing here?

Comment: First time I hear about the "actor pattern", I know the "actor model", but it has seldom to do with that, can you link to the original article?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The benefits are not to a single call but to the sum of all calls.

For example you can use this to limit actual execution to a single goroutine and thereby avoid all the problems concurrent execution would bring with it.

For example I use this pattern to synchronise all usage of a connection to a hardware device that talks serial.

Comment: Could you expand a little bit more? In the above example isn't the synchronization to a single function caller only needed because of the go routine in the first place? If left alone as a "synchronous" handler wouldn't it do the same effect?

Comment: @Rodrigo The actions are executed in the single goroutine running `API.loop()`.  If the actions are called directly in the handler, then the actions run concurrently in the per-connection goroutines started by the net/http server.