# Golang Actor Pattern

Tags: go, actor, goroutine

This is a follow-up to a previous question covering the exact same topic [Benefits of actor pattern in HTTP handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49342232/benefits-of-actor-pattern-in-http-handler)

Below I've repeated the code from that post:

```
func (a *API) handleNext(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var (
        notFound   = make(chan struct{})
        otherError = make(chan error)
        nextID     = make(chan string)
    )
    a.action <- func() {
        s, err := a.log.Oldest()
        if err == ErrNoSegmentsAvailable {
            close(notFound)
            return
        }
        if err != nil {
            otherError <- err
            return
        }
        id := uuid.New()
        a.pending[id] = pendingSegment{s, time.Now().Add(a.timeout), false}
        nextID <- id
    }
    select {
    case <-notFound:
        http.NotFound(w, r)
    case err := <-otherError:
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    case id := <-nextID:
        fmt.Fprint(w, id)
    }
}
```

A single goroutine runs the below loop behind the scenes listening for the action channel. All mutations happen here as the goroutine has exclusive access, acting as a synchronization point:

```
func (a *API) loop() {
    for {
        select {
        case f := <-a.action:
            f()
        }
    }
}
```

The original post questioned the utility of this pattern as the select loop at the bottom of `handleNext` blocks until the func sent to the `action` chan is fired (in the dedicated `loop` goroutine), making every call to `handleNext` run serially.  Answers to the original question stated an overall benefit for the "sum of all goroutines" but I'm not sure I understand how that is the case.

My current expectation is that if we have say 10 clients connected, each calling `handleNext`, they are all immediately blocked until the single dedicated `loop` pulls an item off `action` chan. Since there is only one dedicated goroutine `loop` for firing actions, and those actions must fully complete before the next `handleNext` goroutine can proceed, there is never any concurrent execution of more than one `handleNext`.

I understand that this pattern avoids the need for locking since all mutation would be confined to the `loop` goroutine, but doesn't it also block more than one client from being worked on simultaneously?  If inside of `loop` the call to `f()` was instead `go f()`, then there would be concurrent execution of `handleNext` funcs, but that would defeat the purpose of the pattern since then you would go back to needing to use locks inside the `action` func.

I must be misunderstanding somnething here.

So - I can see that we have lock-free synchronizatinon as a benefit of this pattern, but isn't that at the cost of only working on one client at a time?  If that's true, then how would this be different than just handling one request at a time, serially, without locks or any other synchronization primitives?

Comment: "isn't that at the cost of only working on one client at a time" : in his talk, he illustrates this part by rewriting code that was also running only one action at a time. I guess he wasn't suggesting that you fit *all your code following this one true way*, he was more mentioning that he found more flexibility in having one single channel of `func()`s rather than a bunch of channels `fooReqC, barReqC, ...`

Comment: `how would this be different than just handling one request at a time, serially, without locks or any other synchronization primitives?` How do you implement that in a function being called concurrently if not using channels or mutexes ?

Comment: @LeGEC Yeah I know - the earlier pattern was the same idea, just with a channel per action rather than a channel of closures handling all actions.  I suppose the question applies to both patterns.  I realize it's not the "one true way" but if it's not running api functions concurrently what's the benfeit?

Comment: @mh-cbon - You only have one goroutine at a time processing API requests.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the anonymous function can start a goroutine and return earlier :

```
    a.action <- func() {
        gizmo, err := a.checkGizmoAvailable() // this is run synchronously
        if err != nil {
           otherErr <- err
           return
        }

        // the remainder is run asynchronously
        go func(){
            s, err := gizmo.log.Oldest()
            if err == ErrNoSegmentsAvailable {
                close(notFound)
                return
            }
            if err != nil {
                otherError <- err
                return
            }
            id := uuid.New()
            
            // this will require synchronization :
            a.pending[id] = pendingSegment{s, time.Now().Add(a.timeout), false}
            nextID <- id
        }()

        // returning here, a.loop() can start the next function
    }
```

Comment: OK so this is essentially the scenario I mentioned in my 3rd paragraph above (in the bottom section of the question), right? Without having action run in a separate goroutine (or calling one), the whole thing would be synchronous, never processing more than one request at a time. Here we introduce asynchrony to allow working on multiple clients, but now we have to use locks again - is that right? I'm not sure if the action func presented in the talk is assumed to run in a separate goroutine (or call one) as it wasn't shown in the snippet - I should probably look up the full source.

Comment: yes : if your code allows concurrent access to something, you need to choose a way to synchronize.

Comment: Right - so then the original question remains.  If the primary benefit of this pattern is lock-free synchronization then running `checkGizmoAvailable()` in a different goroutine undermines the intent since we're back to locks.  If we don't run it in a separate goroutine, then isn't this the same as just running everything in a single goroutine without all the channel acrobatics?